# Azure stream analytics - Joining on a csv file returns 0 rows

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
[VanList].deviceId
,[VanList].[VanName]
events.[timestamp]
,events.externaltemp
,events.internaltemp
,events.humidity
,events.latitude    
,events.longitude

INTO
    [iot-powerBI]
FROM
    [iot-EventHub] as events timestamp by [timestamp]
    join [VanList] on events.DeviceId = [VanList].deviceId
```

where iot-eventHub is my event hub and VanList is a reference list (csv file) that has been uploaded to azure storage.

I have tried uploading sample data to test the query, but it always returns 0 rows.

[image]

Below is a sample of the JSON captured by my Event Hub Input

```
    [
   {
      "DeviceId":1,
      "Timestamp":"2015-06-29T12:15:18.0000000",
      "ExternalTemp":9,
      "InternalTemp":8,
      "Humidity":43,
      "Latitude":51.3854942,
      "Longitude":-1.12774682,
      "EventProcessedUtcTime":"2015-06-29T12:25:46.0932317Z",
      "PartitionId":1,
      "EventEnqueuedUtcTime":"2015-06-29T12:15:18.5990000Z"
   } ]
```

Below is a sample of my CSV reference data.

```
deviceId,VanName
1,VAN 1
2,VAN 2
3,Standby Van
```

Both lists contain a device id of 1, so I am expecting my query to be able to join the two together.

I have tried using both "inner join" and "join" in my query syntax, but neither result in a successful join.
What is wrong with my Stream Analytics query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a CAST function in the join. I'm not sure why that works and adding a CREATE TABLE clause for the VanList reference data input doesn't accomplish the same thing. But I think this works.

```
SELECT
[VanList].deviceId
,[VanList].[VanName]
,events.[timestamp]
,events.externaltemp
,events.internaltemp
,events.humidity
,events.latitude    
,events.longitude

INTO
    [iot-powerBI]
FROM
    [iot-EventHub] as events timestamp by [Timestamp]
    join [VanList] on events.DeviceId = cast([VanList].deviceId as bigint)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see is you are missing a comma in your original query, otherwise it looks correct.  I would try recreating the Stream Analytics job.  Here is another example that worked for me.

```
SELECT 
   countryref.CountryName as Geography,
    input.GeographyId as GeographyId

    into [country-out]

FROM input timestamp by [TransactionDateTime]
Join countryref 
on countryref.GeographyID = input.GeographyId here
```

Input data example

```
{"pageid":801,"firstname":"Gertrude","geographyid":2,"itemid":2,"itemprice":79.0,"transactiondatetime":"2015-06-30T14:25:51.0000000","creditcardnumber":"2ggnC"}
    {"pageid":801,"firstname":"Venice","geographyid":1,"itemid":10,"itemprice":169.0,"transactiondatetime":"2015-06-30T14:25:51.0000000","creditcardnumber":"xLyOp"}
    {"pageid":801,"firstname":"Christinia","geographyid":2,"itemid":2,"itemprice":79.0,"transactiondatetime":"2015-06-30T14:25:51.0000000","creditcardnumber":"VuycQ"}
    {"pageid":801,"firstname":"Dorethea","geographyid":4,"itemid":2,"itemprice":79.0,"transactiondatetime":"2015-06-30T14:25:51.0000000","creditcardnumber":"tgvQP"}
    {"pageid":801,"firstname":"Dwain","geographyid":4,"itemid":4,"itemprice":129.0,"transactiondatetime":"2015-06-30T14:25:51.0000000","creditcardnumber":"O5TwV"}
```

Country ref data

```
[
  {
    "GeographyID":1,
    "CountryName":"USA"
  },
  {
    "GeographyID":2,
    "CountryName":"China"
  },
  {
    "GeographyID":3,
    "CountryName":"Brazil"
  },
  {
    "GeographyID":4,
    "CountryName":"Andrews country"
  },
  {
    "GeographyID":5,
    "CountryName":"Chile"
  }
]
```