# Azure Stream Analytics - SQL - Showing 0 rows joining with reference input with SQL Server Reference input

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-stream-analytics

Even reference data available in joining SQL Server reference input tables, no result and no errors

- FROM table, Event hub input
- JOIN tables, SQL Server reference input
- INTO, SQL Server table

```
    SELECT a.Id
          ,SUM(r.FYQ1__c) AS FYQ1__c
          ,SUM(r.FYQ2__c) AS FYQ2__c
          ,SUM(r.FYQ3__c) AS FYQ3__c
          ,SUM(r.FYQ4__c) AS FYQ4__c
    INTO
        [OutRevenueSplitVsAccount]
    FROM
        [RevenueSplitEvHuBIn] AS r TIMESTAMP BY LastModifiedDate  
    INNER JOIN [OpportunityInputTbl] AS o ON r.Opportunity__c = o.Id
    INNER JOIN [AccountInputTbl] AS a ON o.AccountId = a.Id  
    GROUP BY a.Id, TumblingWindow(day,2)
```

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120828/azure-stream-analytics-joining-on-a-csv-file-returns-0-rows  answer your question?

Comment: Yes I checked that and its not resolve the problem, Thanks,